# Odoo Login Redirect Issue : net::err_too_many_redirects

Tags: loops, redirect, authentication, odoo

There is a login issue . Users cannot enter into the Odoo system  , the page redirects .
Error is

```
net::err_too_many_redirects
```

One thing I would like some help understanding is the sudden change of URL for example :

`https://odoowebsite.com` , to  `https://odoowebsite.com/en_GB`

The en_GB at the end of the site may be the reason users cannot login . When I roll back  back to a previous state  the en_GB is removed from the web url.

**I had try with the following attempts on my work.**

1. cleared cache ,
2. removed website module ,
3. restarted the Odoo server with -u all and -d database,
4. removed custom code that inherited website module

can any one have faced this kind of issue ??

Any kind help would be appriciated